# Oracle query to fetch data based upon a order without using order by

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, sql-order-by

Below is the problem statement :

I have a table where we are inserting some data along with a business date of that Hospital along with the create time  stamp.

The business date (Bday) defines the logical day for which the hospital has done the business and the create time stamp (create_ts) defines the timestamp at which the record was inserted in our database.
The business date could be 1 day ahead of the create timestamp as the create timestamp is in PST and the Hospital can be in South Asia, Australia region. 
Also a hospital can be opening for next day if they accidentally closed for today's business date in the application.

I need to sync the record from a staging database to main database.

I want to sync the record with minimum create timestamp first. But order by is a costly operation as sometimes the number of records to be synced are more than 100k

10 Different threads are running to sync the records each with a batch size of 50.

First solution tries was to pickup the records with business date = min business date but there were some complexities:
 1) as there were some records with minimum business date which were not syncing due to some issue as a result the next day records were never picked up without manual interventions.
2) There were hospitals which opened for a future business date ( for example today is 13th and they closed accidentally for it so they were opened for business date 14th ). SO these records did not get process as the business date was greater than min business date.

Thought of picking records where the create timestamp is between minimum create timestamp and +1 hour .
But there could be again issue as mentioned in point (1) and there may not be any record to be synced between the stuck record with minimum create timestamp and +1 hour.

Please suggest a solution for the query

Few columns in the table are : Hname (Hospital Name) , Hloc (Hospital location) , Dseq (Per day sequence number ) , Bday (business date ) , create_ts and modify_ts

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't guaranty the order of the resultset if you don't use "ORDER BY" clause.

But you may consider using [CDC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm) for Oracle 11g or [GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html) for Oracle 12c - it should be very efficient. New data will be replicated almost immediately. Oracle will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for replying ...
Here I dont have to just replicate the data but we are doing a lot of processing in java code .
SO, we can not use oracle replication schemes.
We are already using that where we are having one backup database.

Answer (score 0):

in general: no `order by` --> no guarantee on the order of result set.